# Python's tzinfo to refer a file

Tags: python, date

This is the tzinfo that I have set.

```
tz = {'CST' : -6*3600, 'BST' : +1*3600, 'EST' :-5*3600,'MST':-7*3600,'PST':-8*3600, 'CDT' :-5*3600, 'EDT' : -4*3600, 'PDT':-7*3600}

dt = parser.parse(date,default = DEFAULT_DATE, tzinfos=tz)
```

I want to write all the time zones of America and Europein tz . I don't want to do it manually. Is there a way to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) package:

```
tzinfos = {}
for timezone in pytz.all_timezones:
   if timezone.startswith(("Europe", "US")):

       tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
       start = datetime(2013, 1, 1)
       # loop over the whole year to catch daylight savings, got to be a better way
       for days_delta in range(356):
           d_time = tz.normalize((start + timedelta(days=days_delta)).replace(tzinfo=tz))
           tzinfos[d_time.tzname()] = d_time.utcoffset().total_seconds()
print tzinfos
```

Correct handling of currently not active timezones is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry but I am just a beginner. How should I build the dictionary?

Comment: when I write: 
a = datetime.datetime.now(tm)
       print a.utcoffset()
gives me output -1 day, 19:00:00
How should I convert this into the format I specified in my question like 'CST':-6*3600